# How to implement i18n localization in next for static site generated (SSG) pages

Tags: reactjs, localization, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I have implemented two different third party packages to achieve localization for static site generated (SSG) pages, which includes next-i18next and next-translate. Both of them are working fine for server rendered and client side rendered pages. I am trying to make them work for static site generated pages and unable to do this so far. I have implemented manual solution as well, and no success so far. I have some questions:

1. Can we achieve localization of static site generated pages in next?
2. If yes, can you provide some kind of example to achieve localization for SSG pages.

Comment: with next 10.0 internationalization should work out of the box . https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Comment: Beside of i18n itself, I recommend `attranslate` to semi-automate the file-synchronization for SSG pages: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate I could give you a more complete example, but I am not allowed because of closed-source policies.